# python-xarray plotting with cartopy

Tags: matplotlib, python-xarray, cartopy

I would like to use the `cartopy` plotting function associated with `xarray`. However, I can't work out why the contouring is different compared to stand alone `cartopy`. I'm also not sure how to pass settings for the `plt.colorbar`.

I have a file with spatially varying nans and the plotting functions seems to struggle with this. I'm just hoping to understand how the plotting function works are why it so different from the [tutorial plots](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/plotting.html#two-dimensions)

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import cartopy.crs as ccrs  
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

modellist = ['CCSM4'] # Choose from CCSM4 (1982-2015), CanCM4 (1981-2011), CanCM3 (1981-2011), CFSV2 (1982-2010), GloSea5 (1994-2015 (no 09ic)), System4 (1994-2015), System5 (1993-2014)
modelsave = "".join(modellist)
observation = 'ERAI'    
years_arr=range(1994,2011)    
ic = '12' # 09, 10, 11, 12
varstr = 'ws10'
timeavg = 'DJFmean'
skillmetric = 'rmse'
if varstr == 'ws10': 
    units = r'm $s^{-1}$'

# Download the netCDF file from 
# https://miami.box.com/s/m80adf8dww1aslzb7g6louwzhvujsr54
filein = skillmetric + '_' + ic +'ic_' + modelsave + '_' + observation + '_' + varstr + '_' + timeavg + '_' + str(years_arr[0]) + '-' + str(years_arr[-1]) + '.nc'
da = xr.open_dataarray(filein)    
rmse = da.values

# 2D plot doesn't really work. See plot at http://imgur.com/a/J3TMQ
da.plot()

# Some plot settings:
lon = da.coords['longitude'].values
lat = da.coords['latitude'].values
lon180 = urb.lonto180(lon)
cen_lat = (lat[-1] - lat[0]) / 2.0
cen_lon = ((abs(lon180[-1]) + abs(lon180[0])) / 2.0) + lon180[0]
lonticks = np.arange(lon180[0], lon180[-1]+0.01, 20.0)
latticks = np.arange(lat[0], lat[-1]+0.01, 10.0)
clevsmean = np.linspace(0, 2, 64)
mean_ticks = np.arange(0, 2.01, 0.5) 

# Try to call cartopy from the DataArray
# see plot at http://imgur.com/a/R7sI4
# Some issues with contour e.g. meridian and Pacific
# I also couldn't work out how to edit the colorbar
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=cen_lon)) 
ax.set_extent([lon180[0]-0.01, lon180[-1]+0.01, lat[0]-0.01, lat[-1]+0.01], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines(resolution='50m')
gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True, alpha=0)
gl.xlabels_top = False
gl.ylabels_right = False
gl.xlocator = mticker.FixedLocator(lonticks)
gl.ylocator = mticker.FixedLocator(latticks)
gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER 
da.plot.contourf(ax=ax, levels=clevsmean, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap='jet')
#cbar = plt.colorbar(p=da, ticks=mean_ticks)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, facecolor='black')
plt.title(modelsave + ' ' + ic + 'ic - ' + observation + ' ' + timeavg + ' ' + str(years_arr[0]) 
          + '-' + str(years_arr[-1]) + ' \n' + varstr + ' ' + skillmetric, fontsize=8)    

# Cartopy plot using the np.darray
# See plot at http://imgur.com/a/A9D58
plt.figure(figsize=(5.12985642927, 3))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=cen_lon))   
ax.set_extent([lon180[0]-0.01, lon180[-1]+0.01, lat[0]-0.01, lat[-1]+0.01], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines(resolution='50m')
gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True, alpha=0)
gl.xlabels_top = False
gl.ylabels_right = False
gl.xlocator = mticker.FixedLocator(lonticks)
gl.ylocator = mticker.FixedLocator(latticks)
gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
p = ax.contourf(lon180, lat, rmse, clevsmean, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap='jet')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, facecolor='black')
cbar = plt.colorbar(p, ticks=mean_ticks)
cbar.set_label(units)
plt.title(modelsave + ' ' + ic + 'ic - ' + observation + ' ' + timeavg + ' ' + str(years_arr[0]) 
          + '-' + str(years_arr[-1]) + ' \n' + varstr + ' ' + skillmetric, fontsize=8)
```

Comment: So what is the question?